# How to generate a random string in ruby selenium that can be used in a text field

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'd like to know how I can generate a random string, e.g. `TufwGfXZskHlPcYrLNKg`.

This would be used to create a new teaching class within our application, but for the purposes of testing I'd like to assign a random name to each class that gets created.

At the moment I use a variable that is held elsewhere in an `application.yml` file, e.g.

```
qa_newclass_name: 'Cucumber'
```

During the test I then assign this to the step like so:
`@wait.until {@driver.find_element(:css => '#name').click}
@driver.find_element(:css => '#name').send_keys (Figaro.env.qa_newclass_name)`

What this will do is make the name of the class 'Cucumber'

Instead of specifying 'Cucumber' for each test, is there a simple way to generate something random that I can assign to the #name field? Perhaps this can be a function that can generate the string in-line with the rest of the code above?

This should be in Ruby of course, ideally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way would be something like:

```
require 'securerandom'

@driver.find_element(...).send_keys (SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5).gsub(/[^a-z ]/i, '').upcase)
```

The regex is necessary because `#urlsafe_base64` may generate characters like `-` and `_`. Upcasing is necessary because you're looking to define a constant, and a lowercase letter may be the first character of the random string as-is.

A solution without the required module and regex could look something like:

```
@driver.find_element(...).send_keys ((5.times).map{(65 + rand(26)).chr}.join)
```